# IIS site will not open .htm or php files

Tags: php, iis-7, coldfusion-8

Platform: IIS 7.5 on Windows Web Server 2008 R2

I have a site that has stopped allowing .htm and .php files to open, behaviour with each file type in different browsers is as follows:

.HTM FILES

Firefox promtps to download
IE opens fine
Chrome opens it as plain text

.PHP FILES

Firefox display File Not Found
IE prompts to download
Chrome opens fine

This was working up until around a month ago, there are rewrites in place on this domain but we've removed them to see if it makes a difference and it didn't.

Other IIS sites on the same server work fine, we've compared the settings and can find no difference at all in configuration.

There is no .htaccess file in use although Helicon Ape is installed.

This server is also running Coldfusion 8 but this is configured for all sites so it that was the issue it should also affect the others but does not.

Comment: Its seems like that the connector is failing. Try recreating the connector for ColdFusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the MIME types in IIS - added the text/htm and text/html ones and it worked.